# distinct value from a column in a grid using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am using the below query to find the the distinct value count from a dataset column. How to find similarly to a grid column.

```
var distinctRows = (from DataRow dRow in _ds.Tables[0].Rows
                    select dRow["colName"]).Distinct();
```

Comment: How is your grid populated?  Is it bound to a DataTable or an ObjectDataSource?

Comment: bound  to dataset. but i can not use query in dataset to get distinct values since it affects one of my scenario

Comment: I'm not sure there's enough information to give you a good answer.  What scenario would prevent you from using the query against the DataSet?

Comment: i will add some values to the dataset through some other grid and if any exceptions only few records are updated and after that i need to check the value in the grid for uniquness

Comment: Can you post the code you have?  It seems to me that you should be able to check the grid for uniqueness, but maybe I'm not getting something that the code may make clearer.

Comment: or else if i could get an answer on how to get count of unique number of rows for a column in a grid should be sufficient can you please help

Comment: I gave it a shot - see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok..I'm still not sure why you want to do it without requerying the DataSource, but here's one way that might point you in the right direction.  gv1 is the ID of your `GridView`, and for demonstration purposes I'll use the first column:

```
string[] rowValues = new string[gv1.Rows.Count];

for (int i = 0; i < gv1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    rowValues[i] = gv1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text;
}

var distinctRows = (from r in rowValues
                    select r).Distinct();
```

This of course assumes that it's one cell per column, which may be a false (or at least bad) assumption.

**UPDATE**
Just saw this [Can't seem to use Linq with ASP.Net Navigation menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954163/cant-seem-to-use-linq-with-asp-net-navigation-menu) answered by Jon Skeet, and think it might apply to the issue here.

```
var distinctRows = (from GridViewRow r in gv1.Rows
                    select r.Cells[0].Text).Distinct();
```

Courtesy of Jon's answer, to use LINQ in this case you need to `Cast` to IEnumerable (as I'm willing to bet the GridViewRowsCollection doesn't implement IEnumerable) by explicitly specifying the item, as above.

Answer (score 0):

Your grid is probably bound to a data source in which case it makes more sense to use the linq query against the data source rather than the grid itself

Comment: That dataset will be updated once again through the grid and i have a scenario in which only few values are updated remaining values are not updated to dataset. so i need to have the query only through grid

Comment: Any other suggestion  if any?