# Can't seem to use Linq with ASP.Net Navigation menu

Tags: c#, linq, navigationbar

I have the following piece of code:

```
        // Iterate through the root menu items in the Items collection.
        foreach (MenuItem item in NavigationMenu.Items)
        {
            if (item.NavigateUrl.ToLower() == ThisPage.ToLower())
            {
                item.Selected = true;
            }
        }
```

What I'd like is:

```
var item = from i in NavigationMenu.Items
           where i.NavigateUrl.ToLower() == ThisPage.ToLower()
           select i;
```

Then I can set the `Selected` value of `item`, but it gives me an error on the `NavigationMenu.Items`.

> Error 5   Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for
>   source type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.MenuItemCollection'.  'Where'
>   not found.  Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range
>   variable 'i'.

When I comment out the `where` clause, I get this error:

> Error 22  Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for
>   source type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.MenuItemCollection'.  'Select'
>   not found.  Consider explicitly specifying the type of the range
>   variable 'i'.

Comment: For future reference, it's worth really reading the error message - it's given exactly the same advice as I have: explicitly specifying the type of the range variable.

Comment: That message happens when I commented out the `where` part of the Linq statement.  It gave me a different error when I uncomment the `where` statement.

Comment: @Neil: And what was *that* error message? In general, on Q&A sites like this, it's never a good idea to say "it gave me an error" without specifying the error message itself.

Comment: @Neil: It's not a *very* different error message - it still tells you exactly what you need to do to fix it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect `NavigationMenu.Items` only implements `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<T>`. To fix this, you probably want to call `Cast`, which can be done by explicitly specifying the element type in the query:

```
var item = from MenuItem i in NavigationMenu.Items
           where i.NavigateUrl.ToLower() == ThisPage.ToLower()
           select i;
```

However, your query is named misleadingly - it's a *sequence* of things, not a single item.

I'd also suggest using a [`StringComparison`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison.aspx) to compare the strings, rather than upper-casing them. For example:

```
var items = from MenuItem i in NavigationMenu.Items
            where i.NavigateUrl.Equals(ThisPage, 
                                 StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
            select i;
```

I'd then consider using extension methods instead:

```
var items = NavigationMenu.Items.Cast<MenuItem>()
            .Where(item => item.NavigateUrl.Equals(ThisPage, 
                                 StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: Ohh...that's a neat trick!  I wish I'd know about the `Cast` earlier.